# Magento 2 add to cart button not showing for any product

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart

On my magento website, add to cart button is not showing on any product page. I have checked inventory, visibility settings everything is correct still its not showing.
can anyone please help regarding this in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Have you recently edited or added any css ? or installed any new theme ? Try changing your theme and check if it's coming or not

Comment: have you checked availability and Is in stock options on products? Button disappear 'like that; with no reason or You or someone else did something with code?

Comment: we did reimport of all products again to update descriptions ad images , and after that the button stopped showing

Comment: Go to the admin side , edit a particular product  and under  the Design tab, set the option  Display Product Options In as Product Info Column and save. Run re index and check if the add to cart button is coming for that particular product.

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Open `vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\` and copy "**fonts**" folder to your theme i.e. `app\design\frontend\Package\Theme\web`

It should work